# Matlab symbolic computation of x*x^T

Tags: matlab

This is probably very trivial for folks experienced with MATLAB but I am struggling with a simple calculation of vector*vector^T

```
>> syms x1 x2 x3
>> x = [x1;x2;x3]

x =

 x1
 x2
 x3

>> x*x'

ans =

[ x1*conj(x1), x1*conj(x2), x1*conj(x3)]
[ x2*conj(x1), x2*conj(x2), x2*conj(x3)]
[ x3*conj(x1), x3*conj(x2), x3*conj(x3)]
```

What I would like to see is

```
[ x1*x1, x1*x2, x1*x3]
[ x2*x1, x2*x2, x2*x3]
[ x3*x1, x3*x2, x3*x3]
```

without the `conj()`s

Is there a way to write my vector x or a product function to get the desired fresult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x'` or [`ctranspose(x)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) is the complex conjugate transpose operator. Use `x.'`
or [`transpose(x)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) for the non-conjugate transpose.

Comment: Or define symbolic variables as real if they are assumed to be so: `syms x1 x2 x3 real`.